# Using UUID() with json in swift

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

I have found examples online that use hardcoded uuids in the json file and the works perfectly for me, however as I am adding the ability to delete items from the json array in my app I need these uuid's to be created dynamically

Here is my json file (list.json), it used to have hard coded ids like "id": 1 and worked (when I used int for ids )

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Dune",
    "author": "Frank Herbert",
    "page": "77"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ready Player One",
    "author": "Ernest Cline",
    "page": "234"
  },
  {
    "name": "Murder on the Orient Express",
    "author": "Agatha Christie",
    "page": "133"
  }
]
```

Here is my struct (Book.swift)

```swift
struct Book: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var author: String
    var page: String
}
```

When I decode my json file using this struct with the code (Data.swift)...

```swift
let bookData: [Book] = load("list.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }
    
    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

my last fatal error is executed because the id key has no value associated with it (because I removed it in my json file)

How do I initialize my json file with an id so that my `id = UUID()` statement in my struct can assign it a unique id?

Answer (score 9):

In this case you have to specify `CodingKeys` and omit `id`

```
struct Book: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let author: String
    let page: String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name, author, page }
}
```

Apparently the struct members are not going to be modified so declare them as constants.

Comment: I have the exact same code (just other name for the struct) but it gives error on "does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'". I have one var that is URL and the rest Strings

Comment: @lopes710 Check the spelling.

Comment: Indeed it was. My 'imageURL' should be 'ImageUrl'. Upvoted and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(I think I saw your post on Reddit.)

You can create an init for the Book struct that generates a UUID. In fact, you can create several inits for an object that ask for different inputs or give defaults for various parameters depending on how you want the construction logic to run. That can be pretty handy.

You should keep the UUID in your CodableKeys if its an essential part of your data structure.

You may want to consider whether a run-time generated UUID will truly unique your objects as you wish. Do you want multiple objects that share the same title and author? A user could forget they added a particular book. Do you want to use ISBNs or try to unique things yourself, such as detect duplicate or close-to-duplicate titles and ask the user if they really mean to double down on two of the same book?

Comment: Yes you saw my reddit post (feral____ right?), I implemented the init, I also decided to implement isbns in version 2 update once my app is working well.

Comment: Sounds like a challenge. Interim effort is a friendly de-duping message. Google Books and Open Library have APIs to populate book details with requests.

Comment: Those apis look interesting, once I gain some proper understanding of JSONencodable, ill start working on error messages in my app

Answer (score -1):

Okay so here is my solution. Rather than dynamically filling the id field now, I will fill them when I am using an Encodable function with variable = UUID().uuidstring. Therefore my examples will have hardcoded ids but when people add their own books to my app, my app will generate the id. Its a simple solution but as a beginner I didn't know what to look for.